# Is it possible to assign and retrieve a value to/from a certain cursor position with VIM script?

Tags: vim

I was wondering if there is method to assign a value with a cursor position and later retrieve this value even if the text was modified after the assignment and before its retrieval.

That is, if I have say the following text in a buffer

```
apple pear lemon
london berlin paris boston
foo bar baz
one two three four
```

and then would call (within a VIM script) something like

```
call AssignValue(1, 6, "Second Fruit")
call AssignValue(3, 5, "BAR")
```

and then would (manually or script wise) insert some text so that the buffer now looks like

```
SOME NEW CHARACTERS apple pear lemon
MY NEWLY ADDED LINE
london berlin paris boston
foo bar baz
one two three four
```

then I'd like to have a function that returns *Second Fruit* for

```
let var=RetrieveValue(1, 26)
```

and *BAR* from

```
let var=RetrieveValue(4,5)
```

Answer (score 0):

This may work, up to some extent:

Make the function AssignValue associate the string you wish to save ("Second Fruit", "BAR") with the word at the given cursor position, i.e. save it into a dictionary.

With that in place RetrieveValue can lookup the word at the given cursor position and retrieve the corresponding stored value in the dictionary.